# CSS Float Overlap Issue

Tags: html, css, css-float

Can anyone help with a basic HTML/CSS float issue? I have a regular div with a float left div box. I wanted to have a h1 with a border but it overlaps into the float left div. Any tips? Sample code to show issue below.

[EDIT:  Here is an image of the issue: http://anony.ws/i/2012/06/21/UCHvY.png. I'd like the end result to simply allow me to use the blue line for the h1 without it overlapping on the left.  The height of the left column is dynamic]

```
<style>
.wrapper {width:600px;}
.boxcolumn {
            float:left;
    width:150px;
    border:1px red solid;
    margin-right:12px;
}
h1 {border-bottom:1px #CCC solid;}
```

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="boxcolumn">
Left Column is not a fixed height. Left Column is not a fixed height.Left Column is not a fixed height.Left Column is not a fixed height.Left Column is not a fixed height.Left Column is not a fixed height.Left Column is not a fixed height.Left Column is not a fixed height.Left Column is not a fixed height.Left Column is not a fixed height.Left Column is not a fixed height.Left Column is not a fixed height.Left Column is not a fixed height.Left Column is not a 
</div> 

<h1>Some Title Goes Here</h1>
blah blah blah blah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blah

<h1>Some Title Goes Here</h1>Left Column is not a fixed height.Left Column is not a fixed height.Left Column is not a 
</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand, you want the h1 below?

Comment: There seems to be different ideas floating around about how to solve your problem. I think it would be helpful if you could present a wireframe example of how you are expecting your layout to be.

Comment: Added a screen shot showing what I'm trying to achieve  http://anony.ws/i/2012/06/21/UCHvY.png

Answer (score 0):

Try this... Your h1 tag also needs to float left and it should have a width on it. Also 
it should come before your box column.

```
<style type="text/css">
.wrapper {width:600px;}
.boxcolumn {
    float:left;
    width:150px;
    border:1px red solid;
    margin-right:12px;
}
h1 {border-bottom:1px #CCC solid;float:left;width:100%;}
</style>

<div class="wrapper">
<h1>Some Title Goes Here</h1>
<div class="boxcolumn">
Left Column is not a fixed height. Left Column is not a fixed height.Left Column is not a fixed height.Left Column is not a fixed height.Left Column is not a fixed height.Left Column is not a fixed height.Left Column is not a fixed height.Left Column is not a fixed height.Left Column is not a fixed height.Left Column is not a fixed height.Left Column is not a fixed height.Left Column is not a fixed height.Left Column is not a fixed height.Left Column is not a 
</div> 


blah blah blah blah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blah
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try making another div with the title and text and floating that one next to it:

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="boxcolumn">
       Left Column is not a fixed height. Left Column is not a fixed height.Left Column is not a fixed height.Left Column is not a fixed height.Left Column is not a fixed height.Left Column is not a fixed height.Left Column is not a fixed height.Left Column is not a fixed height.Left Column is not a fixed height.Left Column is not a fixed height.Left Column is not a fixed height.Left Column is not a fixed height.Left Column is not a fixed height.Left Column is not a 
   </div> 

   <div class="title">
       <h1>Some Title Goes Here</h1>
       blah blah blah blah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blah
   </div>
</div>
```

You'll need to set a width to title though:

```
    .title {
        float:left;
        width:400px;
    }
```

Comment: If I set the width to the title, any text that goes below the left column would be that same width. I'd like it to extend all the way to the end. See http://anony.ws/i/2012/06/21/UCHvY.png as an example.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of options you could try.

One of them is wrapping your `h1` and text into a new `div`. Then give this `div` a `float: left;` and `width: 436px;` (600 - 150 - 12 - 2*1 border). This makes sure your content is wrapped to the right of the `boxcolumn` and stays that way even if your content is longer than the `boxcolumn`.

```
<div class="content">
<h1>Some Title Goes Here</h1>
<p>blah blah blah blah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blah</p>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.content{ float:left; width: 436px; }
```

Full example can be seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/KsBAW/)

Comment: Thanks, but I'd like the text to go beneath the left column as well. Your example would just create 2 distinct columns.